# How to display the relevant information from object based on selected tabs using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have the data structure (object) like below

```
const Items = {
    id: '1',
    Orders: [
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Order1',
        }
        {
            id: '3',
            title: 'Order2',
        }
    ],
    subItems: [
        { 
            id: '1',
            Orders: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    title: 'subitem1-order1',
                    status: 'new',
                }
                {
                    id: '2',
                    title: 'subitem1-order2',
                    status: 'done',
                }
            ],
        }
        { 
            id: '2',
            Orders: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    title: 'subitem2-order1',
                    status: 'new',
                }
                {
                    id: '2',
                    title: 'subitem2-order2',
                    status: 'done',
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

As seen from above data, the items object has Orders and subItems that has multiple Orders too.

i have two tabs. Orders and subItem Orders. when user clicks on Orders tab i should list only the Orders for the Items object so the result should be

Order1 and Order2

similarly when user clicks the tab subItem Orders the result should be

subitem1-order1, subitem1-order2, subitem2-order1 and subitem2-order2

Also there are filter divs like all, new, done, accepted. it defaults to all meaning all the orders of status anything new, done or accepted will be shown.
if users clicks filter new it lists orders (both orders and subitem orders) of status new
if user clicks filter done it lists orders (both orders and subitem orders) of status done
if user clicks filter accepted it lists orders (both orders and subitem orders) of status accepted.

below is my code that currently puts the Orders and subItem orders as array of objects and lists them together in the order they were created. I have added the tabs that are not functional yet.

```
export enum TabOptions {
    Orders = 'Orders',
    SubItemOrders = 'SubItemOrders',
}

function getAllOrders(items) {
    return [
        ...(items.Orders || []),
        ...(items.subItems
        ? items.subItems.reduce((acc: any, subItem) => {
            return [...acc, ...(subItem.Orders || [])];
        }, [])
          : []),
    ];
}

export const useOrdersByFilter = (items) => {
    return React.useMemo(() => {
        const Orders = getAllOrders(items); //this groups all orders and subitem orders into one array of objects

        const sortedOrders = orderBy(Orders,
            ({ startDate }) => new Date(startDate),
            ['asc']
        );

        const delayedOrders = sortedOrders.filter(o => {
            const now = moment();
            const end = moment(o.endDate);
            const isDelayed =
                o.status !== OrderStatus.DONE && end.isBefore(now, 'day');
            return isDelayed;
        });

        const byStatus = groupBy(sortedOrders, 'status');

        return {
            [OrderFilter.ALL]: sortedOrders,
            [OrderFilter.COMPLETE]: byStatus[OrderStatus.DONE] || [],
            [OrderFilter.DELAYED]: delayedOrders,
        };
    }, [item]);
};


function Parent () {
    const items; //this has value as the items data structure that i mentioned above.
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = React.useState(TabOptions.Orders);//this             keeps track of tab that user clicked.defaulted to Orders tab.
    const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = React.useState<OrderFilter>(
        OrderFilter.ALL
    ); //this keeps track of filter type that user selected. default to all.


    const OrdersByFilter = useOrdersByFilter(items);
    const allOrders = OrdersByFilter[OrderFilter.ALL] || [];

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Content>
                <span> title</span>
                <Tabs>
                    <Tab
                        onClick={() => setSelectedTab(TabOptions.Orders)}
                        className={selectedTab === TabOptions.Orders ? 'active' : ''}
                    >
                        <span>Orders</span>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab
                        onClick={() => setSelectedTab(TabOptions.SubItemOrders)}
                        className={selectedTab === TabOptions.SubItemOrders ?             'active' : ''}
                    >
                        <span>subItem-Orders</span>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
                {allOrders.length > 0 &&
                    <OrderFilters //this component displays the filter bars based on  the orders  that have been added recently. if there is new Order added by user of status say 'done' then it adds filter for done. similarly for others too.
                        activeFilter={activeFilter}
                        onFilterChange={setActiveFilter}
                        Orders={allOrders}
                    </OrderFilter>
                }

                <OrdersWrapper> //this is the one that lists the orders (both the orders and subitem-orders in the same list
                    <OrderList Orders={OrdersByFilter[activeFilter]} /> 
                </OrdersWrapper>
            </Content>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
  

    
//the OrderList component lists the orders (both the orders and subitemorders)

function OrderList({Orders}:Props) {
    return (
        {item.data.map(o => {
            return (
              <OrderCardWrapper key={o.id}>
                <OrderCard data={o} /> //this is  div that displays order info.
              </OrderCardWrapper>
            );
          })}
      );
 }
```

the above code displays both orders and subitem orders in one list. but now i want to split them in sections. when user selects orders tab only orders should be seen. when user clicks subitem-orders tab only subitem orders should be seen.

how can i fix the above code. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, I will put only the relevant code here:

First split the *getAllOrders* in 2 functions
(you can get rid of ... operator as reduce will already make a shallow copy)

```
function getAllOrders(items) {
    return [
        ...(items.Orders || []),
    ];
}


function getAllSubOrders(items) {
    return 
        items.subItems ? items.subItems.reduce((acc: any, subItem) => {
             return [...acc, ...(subItem.Orders || [])];
        }, [])
        : []
    ;
}
```

Move the getAllOrder call to the Parent function, so you will be able to call it for each item (orders and subOrders)

```
function Parent() {
    ...       
    const Orders = getAllOrders(items);
    const SubOrders = getAllSubOrders(items);
    const OrdersByFilter = useOrdersByFilter(Orders);
    const SubOrdersByFilter = useOrdersByFilter(SubOrders);
```

Of course now *useOrdersByFilter* accepts orders not items.

```
export const useOrdersByFilter = (Orders) => {
    return React.useMemo(() => {

        const sortedOrders = orderBy(Orders,
        ...
```

Back to the Parent function, *allOrders* should be initialized depending on the user choice (item or subitem):

```
    const allOrders = (selectedTab === TabOptions.SubItemOrders ? SubOrdersByFilter[OrderFilter.ALL] : OrdersByFilter[OrderFilter.ALL]) || [];
```

Comment: thanks a ton. this works as expected. except that i have added ...operator for the getAllSubOrders too. otherwise it gives array of array. and also there is some blinking visible for the change in list when changing selection of tabs. any ideas on what can be causing it? thanks.

Comment: thanks! i'm glad to help. The blinking is visible, i would suspect perf problem, maybe with items initilization (put a console.log in useMemo callback to see if it's called several times), maybe a subcomponent like OrderList is to slow to re-render (remove them one by one to see if blinking disappears)